# Combo Box and Text Box in VBA equal to cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Database
[image: Database]
and my code as below. I able to call out the data show in txtnumber, but isn't the correct data. Beside if I add msg box inside for next, the msg box will keep looping and the data in txtnumber will changing as well.

Does anyone know what happened and assist to correct my code?

```
Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim i As Long 
Dim j As Long 
Dim LastRow As Long 
Dim LastColumn As Long 

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

LastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
LastColumn = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

For i = 2 To LastRow 
    For j = 3 To LastColumn 

    With Me 
        MsgBox ("Hello") 
        If sht.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(.ComboBox1) And sht.Cells(j, "B").Value = Val(.txtgender) Then 
            .txtnumber = sht.Cells(j, "C").Value 
        End If 
    End With 
    Exit For
    Next j 
Next i
```

Comment: you put your msgbox inside a loop  so it will call until the loop ends. and your code tends to change value. What is your goal?

Comment: What do you expect `Exit For` to do?

Comment: I want to do when the combo box selects any Company, enters the gender, and then press submit, the correct number of genders appears on the number side.

Select ABC, enter Male, press submit, number will appear 39 over there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that is somewhat similar to what you were attempting.  I threw out LastRow and used LastColumn so you could see where I was trying to point you.  This example uses many of the same principles you were following but wouldn't be my preferred method.  The merged cells add complexity and you will benefit from solving this problem in different ways before moving on.  The extra practice will also help your understanding of nested loops.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With sht
        LastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 2 To LastColumn Step 2
            If .Cells(4, i + j) = ComboBox1.Value Then
                For j = 0 To 1
                    If Cells(5, i + j) = ComboBox2.Value Then ComboBox3.Value = .Cells(6, i + j)
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I know, I need help on this.

Comment: it's no problem. just take it one piece at a time and think it through each step,  i like to think of a video game, like space Invaders.  a little guy on the bottom shooting up. whatever that little guy hits will be declared the last row - be careful though because there might be data to the right that's lower, it's not guaranteed to always be A.  now for last column, it's similar as lastrow but not the same. you have EXACTLY the same.  what needs to change for the little guy to shoot from right to left and hit a olumn?  think about. change your code. test it out.

Comment: If I remove the LastColumn, I can use  LastRow = sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row or sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ?

Comment: the way you're trying to solve this problem requires both lastrow and lastcolumn. if you you remove it then you'll need to change almost everything in your program; it's easier to fix it instead.  to find the last row, you count rows.  to find the last column, do you think you should count rows or count columns (your currently counting rows)?   To answer your question about A or B, with your current sample data - it doesn't matter if you use A or B... or C D E F ot G.  Because they all share the same last row.  I would keep it the way you have it, it isn't broken so I would try to fix it.

Comment: I'm trying to fix it, but I'm still finding the way D: